# Segmentation error when trying to append to linked list, c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a struct defined as such:

```
struct Node { 
    int day = 0; 
    int number = 0;
    Node* next = nullptr; 
};
```

and wrote a create function

```
Node* ll_create(int day, int number){
    Node* p = new Node;
    p->day = day;
    p->number = number;
    p->next = nullptr; 
    return p;
}
```

but my append function always end up in a segmentation error

```
void ll_append(Node* head, int day, int num, int len){
    Node* new_cnode = ll_create(day,num);

    Node* last = head;
    while (last->next != nullptr)
        last = last->next;

    last->next = new_cnode;

}
```

can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Check if head is null

Comment: Can you post how you use ll_append()? Basically, you can not append to a null list.

Comment: You need to extract a [mcve] from your code and provide that as part of your question. While at it, please also remove the trailing ", c++", which is much better represented using language tags. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You have several problems. If it is the first node, presumably `head` is `nullptr` at that point (or worse uninitialized) and it isn't handled in `ll_append()`. If it is set elsewhere and `head` will never change -- then, and only then, can passing `head` by-value to `ll_append()` work. Always better to pass a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the root cause of the issue is `missing error handling`.
i.e. A basic rule can be followed that : before any pointer is dereferenced, it should be validated.

```
void ll_append(Node* head, int day, int num, int len){
    Node* new_cnode = ll_create(day,num);

    Node* last = head;
    while (last->next != nullptr) //Here, last (i.e. head) can be nullptr.
        last = last->next;

    last->next = new_cnode;

}
```

The decision can be taken wheather the caller to `ll_append` shall ensure the `head` or the `ll_append` itself can validate.

The first solution could look like below :

```
void ll_append(Node*& head, int day, int num, int len){
    Node* new_cnode = ll_create(day,num);
    //Case 1 : When head is pointing to empty list, you can create the first node.
    if(not head)
    {
       head = new_node;
       return;
    }
    //Case 2 : When head is pointing to a valid list (i.e. at least one node is present)
    Node* last = head;
    while (last->next != nullptr)
        last = last->next;

    last->next = new_cnode;

}
```

Comment: `head = new_node;` would only modify the local variable `head`, you can pass `head` as `Node*&` to affect the passed value.